# how Read and write binary excel file without com library

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to read and write excel file . it can do with oledb , there is a limitation

1. maximunm characters < 255
2. solution is mono data type , now create table become second sheet (when open excel it is shown as hidden.)

please give proper answer

Answer (score 1):

There's <strike>two</strike>three (***Thanks Behrooz***) ways of doing this, the first is using [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com) to create a ordinary CSV file which can be read by Excel. The other way is to use a common BIFF file format, see here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/biffcsharp.aspx) on how to accomplish this. The third way is to use an ODBC connection to the Excel spreadsheet as shown here on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ReadExcel07.aspx) also. The fastest way of doing it IMHO is to work with the BIFF format. Also here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Excel_DataReader.aspx) is a fast Excel reader, similar to the DataReader class but for Excel only.

OpenOffice.org has extensive documentation on the binary format for the excel spreadsheets [here](http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf), this is a PDF document which outlines the BIFF layout and structure.

**Edit:** Amended this as **Behrooz** pointed out a small grammer-typo....

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
TOm.

Comment: two ways or three ways?i can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will do it.

You can see live ASP.NET samples with C# and VB source [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself. The trial is fully functional for 30 days.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC